# ARC and UIView instance variables

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I have a UIView instance variable that I add to a another view as a subview;

Does calling removeFromSuperview dealloc an instance variable when using ARC? Or can I add it again to a different view?

Comment: It does not **deallocate,** but it **releases** it.

Comment: Thanks, so with automatic refernce counting is it safe to alloc init a uiview ivar, add it as a subview, then at some point later call removefromsuperview and then at a later point add the same uiview as a subview to another view? Or am I risking a null pointer error by trying to add it as a subview after removefromsuperview was called?

Comment: Java bindings, huh? Objective-C has no NULL pointer errors. Also, releasing doesn't NULL out pointers (at least not under non-ARC, not sure about ARC). But for your question: if you also have a reference to it, and not only its superview references it, then yes, it's safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a strong pointer to the view you're adding/removing, than calling `removeFromSupeview` will not cause the object to be deallocated. You can have a strong pointer by either declaring the UIView as an ivar, or declaring it as a strong property (preferred).

However, if you have no other strong pointer to the view, then it will be deallocated by ARC if you remove it from its superview. (the superview was keeping a strong pointer, and you are breaking that connection.)

Comment: Having a local variable reference to it (which you probably do if you are removing a view from it's superview) will also keep a retain on the object in ARC until that reference is changed or the method returns.

Comment: @BergQuester isn't having a pointer to something the same as having a retain count on it?

Comment: @nick then declared as a strong property it's ok to add and removefromsuperview multiple times?

Comment: Yes that will work fine. Remember to removeFromSuperview before adding to a new view. 
@abbood, having a -Strong- pointer to something is pretty much the same as having a retain count. This is not true for weak pointers.

Comment: @abbood In ARC, mostly, there are weak pointers though. In non-ARC, absolutely not, you have to manage the retain count separately.